# Подстановка переменных в javascript

Tags: javascript, google-spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

Пишу бота в Aimylogic. Он использует в себе элементы javascript. В них и проблема:

Есть переменная $d_y1, в ней записан массив, огромный массив. Чтобы вытащить элемент этого массива, нужно написать $d_y1.индекс

Название индекса хранится в двух других переменных по частям: $nombyk и $nomklass

По логике, нужно написать следующее выражение:

```
$rd_y1 = $d_y1 + "." + $nombyk + $nomklass
```

Поясню: $новая_переменная = $название_массива + "точка" + $первая_часть_индекса + $вторая_часть_индекса

Но в итоге я получаю следующее:
{весь массив целиком}.$значение_первой_переменной$значение_второй_переменной

По логике я имею в виду к **названию переменной** подставить по частям название индекса, а выражение применяется к **содержанию переменной**.

Мой вопрос команда поддержка aimylogic решает уже второй день! Там знающие люди работают, даже они не понимают как это решить
Попробовал еще следующие варианты

1 вариант:

`$rd_y1 = "$d_y1" + "." + $nombyk + $nomklass` (переменная $d_y1 теперь в кавычках)

Получаю в переменной `$rd_y1: $session.d_y1.b9`

Далее убрал командой `$rd_y1 = $rd_y1.replace ("session", "")`. Но пустоту он заменяет на точку и опять получается не то

2 вариант:

`$rd_y1 = "$" + "d_y1" + "." + $nombyk + $nomklass
(разделил $d_y1 по частям)

Получаю в переменной $rd_y1: $d_y1.{знач. переменной}{знач. переменной}

Как бы то что надо, но массив превратился в обыкновенные символы и уже не получается брать из него данные

Comment: Вы лучше покажите весь JS; по отрывкам не очень понятно в чем трудность возникает. Что значит "$название_массива"(имя переменной в которой хранится массив?) и "массив превратился в обыкновенные символы и уже не получается брать из него данные"?

Comment: через точку - это к объектам, а массив лучше через скобки `$rd_y1 = $d_y1[$nombyk + $nomklass]`

Answer (score 0):

Всю структуру данных, значения переменных $nombyk + $nomklass и ожидаемый результат в студию пожалуйста. Jean-Claude прав, в массиве нужно использовать квадратные скобки [$nombyk + $nomklass], когда Вы используете + '.' или + 9 или все вместе, вы превращаете массив в обычную строку добавляя к ней точку и индекс. Если значение двух переменных это b9, то это не индекс, ибо индекс массива это число, больше подходит для ключа объекта